# Какой выбрать bb редактор для комментариев на блоге?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, редактор

Здравствуйте. Нужен приятный на вид, удобный редактор с возможностью вставки кода. Желательно, чтобы кастомизация тегов там была упрощена. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WysiBB - самый простой. Чуток с большим функционалом - TinyMCE.